# Unable to create EXTERNAL TABLE at Azure SQL SERVER

Tags: azure, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE EX_SOURCE 
WITH ( 
TYPE = RDBMS,
LOCATION = 'SERVER.database.windows.net',
DATABASE_NAME = 'DB_NAME',
CREDENTIAL = "CREDENTIAL"
);
```

Getting error, Incorrect syntax near EXTERNAL.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can only run `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` as an elastic database query which has to be on a V12 database.

You can find more information on running this query on the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn935022.aspx